# generate html in axure. adaptive views without js

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, axure

I created a simple page with Axure in 2 versions (basically 2 adaptive views: base and 768 and below). When I generate the html, it works fine and follows the adaptive views. But this seems to work only with javascript, is there a way to deal with/generate the adaptive views in css? This could help me later on integrating the Axure generated html and css into my responsive design based on bootstrap. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're asking about responsiveness according to screen size.  Bootstrap is built around these principles and the responsiveness is done purely through CSS using @media queries.  All CSS starts on the smallest possible screen and then you can adjust your CSS to change as the screen size gets larger by placing @ media queries at the bottom of your stylesheet.  They are as follows:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {

This is where your CSS for anything above 768px goes

}

@media (min-width:992px) {

This is where your CSS for anything above 992px goes

}

@media (min-width:1200px) {

This is where your CSS for anything above 1200px goes

}
```

You can also use max-width in media queries

Comment: Thanks Jake, do you know if there is a way for Axure to do it this way when the html is generated? If I have to to it manually after the html is exported, I lose all the advantage of adaptive views in Axure (which seem to work pretty well, but apparently thanks to javascript only)

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can.  Read this article about Axure and responsive design and then read the comments as well.  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/26/creating-responsive-prototypes-with-adaptive-views-in-axure-rp-7/  You'll see that bootstrap is a much better way to go.  Oh...and don't forget to accept my answer as the correct one.  Thanks